# Write journald metadata to rsyslog

Tags: logging, docker, systemd, rsyslog

I have a setup where docker containers use the `journald` log driver to write their logs. Currently log lines from the journal are forwarded to rsyslog running on the host, but the application name on the syslog lines appears as `dockerd`.

As a workaround, I'd like to write the `CONTAINER_NAME` field form the journal metadata into the line that appears in syslog, so I can identify what container wrote what line after the host's syslog has been shipped to a syslog aggregation server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by defining a template after parsing the structured logs from journald. For figuring out what properties were available I ran `journalctl -o verbose  -n 10`

rsyslog has multiple different ways to do the same configuration, here is my config from a CentOS 7 machine:

```
module(load="imjournal" StateFile="imjournal.state") # Load imjournal module
module(load="mmjsonparse") # Load mmjsonparse module for structured logs

action(type="mmjsonparse") # Attempt to parse JSON

template(name="ContainerTemplate" type="list") {
    property(name="timestamp" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="$!CONTAINER_NAME")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="$!CONTAINER_ID")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="$!MESSAGE")
    constant(value="\n") # Separate logs with a newline
}

if ($!CONTAINER_NAME != "") then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/messages" template="ContainerFormat")
} else {
    *.info;mail.none;news.none;authpriv.none;cron.none action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/messages")
}
```

#### Reference documentation:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/journald/
- http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imjournal.html
- http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/mmjsonparse.html
- http://www.rsyslog.com/using-rsyslog-and-elasticsearch-to-handle-different-types-of-json-logs/
- http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html
- http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/control_structures.html#if-else-if-else

Answer (score 1):

I think closest you could get image name. You can add a log tag to show the image name in logs. This feature has been  added in v1.11.0. For example:

```
docker run --log-driver=journald --log-opt tag="{{.ImageName}}
```

Have a look at [log tag docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/log_tags/) too. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately when I set the `tag` opt it sets the `CONTAINER_TAG` in the journal metadata, which shows in the output of `docker logs` and various `journalctl` commands, but doesn't seem to show in the lines written to to `/var/log/syslog`. Do you see different behavior?

Comment: @Michael were you able to solve this ? I have the same question

Comment: @Sandeep Unfortunately I've not been able to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by putting this in rsyslog.conf

`if ( $!CONTAINER_TAG == "mycontainer" ) then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/mycontainer.log")
    stop
}`

I can test that it works with this 

`docker run  --log-driver=journald --log-opt tag="mycontainer" centos:latest echo Pierre7`

I get my log both in the file /var/log/mycontainer and in the journal, which I can find with

`journalctl --unit docker CONTAINER_TAG=mycontainer`

It is difficult to find the information, the only place where it seems documented in in the redhat documentation: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-structured_logging_with_rsyslog.html

My use case is that I want the journal for all the benefits it gives but the support people are requesting to have normal files. Also we will use the splunkforwarder to consume the files.